# Line not drawing to canvas with pixi.dart

Tags: dart, pixi.js

I thought I had what was needed with this code to draw a line to the canvas but seems not. Can I get pointers as to what I did wrong/did not do?

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:pixi/pixi.dart';

class BunnyExample
{
    CanvasRenderer renderer    = new CanvasRenderer(width: 400, height: 300);
    Stage stage       = new Stage(new Colour.fromHtml('#ffffff'));
    Graphics graph = new Graphics();

    BunnyExample()
    {
        document.body.append(this.renderer.view);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(_lineAnim);
    }

    void _lineAnim(var num)
    {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this._lineAnim);
      graph
      ..position = new Point(0, 0)
      ..pivot = new Point(50, 50)
      ..lineStyle(1,new Colour(255, 0, 0))
      ..beginFill(new Colour(255,0,0))
      ..lineTo(50, 70)
      ..endFill();
      stage.children.add(graph);
      renderer.render(stage);
    }
}

void main()
{
    new BunnyExample();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to call `moveTo()` before `lineTo()`:

```
void _lineAnim(var num)
{
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this._lineAnim);
  graph
  ..position = new Point(0, 0)
  ..pivot = new Point(50, 50)
  ..lineStyle(1,new Colour(255, 0, 0))
  ..beginFill(new Colour(255,0,0))
  ..moveTo(50, 50)
  ..lineTo(50, 70)
  ..endFill();
  renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Also, it's better to set the stage in the constructor, or you can have a memory leak:

```
BunnyExample()
{
    stage.children.add(graph); //doing this in the animation loop leads to a memory leak
    document.body.append(this.renderer.view);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(_lineAnim);
}
```

Comment: i see thanks for advice...so it doesn't default to starting at 0,0 but rather null and doesn't break your code? Or what's going on? :/

Comment: oh also when i moved to 0,0 and drew to 50,50 i couldn't see anything drawn...what, is the origin outside the canvas? o.O

Comment: If you remove the `position` and `pivot` properties, you can draw a line from 0,0 to 50,50, but I can't explain you why. I'm not an expert with this library, I've just debugged your code to figure out why it's not working :)